# MS Access table validation

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I was wondering if anybody would be able to tell me how to check if multiple fields in a form  are valid or not. Basically I want to set up a validation rule for my last field to check if all of the previous fields are blank or not.

I have already tried this:

```
IsNull([FieldName])
```

I know that this is only for one field, but I can't even get that to work. I am pretty new with access so any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If all fields need to be filled in then why not just set their `Required` property to `Yes` in the table design?

Answer (score 1):

What i would do is in the tag property for each control you want to validate, put a word in there that you can check for (example - enter "VALIDATE" for each control you want checked).  To find the tag property:  look at the property sheet for each control, in the OTHER tab, the last field listed = tag).

Then as code in the afterupdate event of the last control, select EVENT PROCEDURE and enter this code:

```
Dim ctl As Control

For Each ctl In Forms!YourFormName
If ctl.Tag = "validate" Then
    If IsNull(ctl.Value) Then
        ctl.SetFocus
        MsgBox "You must complete the " & ctl.Name & " field.", vbOKOnly, "Required Field Missing"
        GoTo exitsub
    End If 
End If
Next

exitsub:
Exit Sub
```

If this finds and empty field, it will move back to that field, (set focus) and display a message box that states they must enter a value.